# Route traffic to the internet through router and Mikrotik firewall

Tags: router, traffic, mikrotik

I would like to request your help to understand whether my diagram is correct, at least conceptually. Im trying to set a network environment from almost scratch.

We have a fixed IP provided by ISP. Behind it, I have placed a Mikrotik router firewall. Behind the Mikrotik, I have added an ASUS wireless router.

I have internet from the Mikrotik to the internet (meaning, from the 19.168.209.0 to the internet), but not from the ASUS router (not from the 10.0.0.0/24). Im not understanding how the setup of the ASUS has to be done.

In the mikrotik, what I have done is:

- to configure the ether1 as WAN with IP 192.168.1.2, and plug there the cable that goes to the ISP router.
- to configure the ether2 as LAN, with IP 192.168.209.1
- to add a route for the 10.0.0.0/24

In the ASUS wifi router, what I have done is:

to configure the WAN IP as 192.168.209.2
to configure the LAN as 10.0.0.1
enable DHCP
The traffic from the ASUS is not even reaching the Mikrotik. It keeps saying unreachable. I tried to add a default route towards the gateway 192.168.209.1 but it did not work.

Im missing something basic here, hope you can give a hand.

[image]

Comment: Hi @sawesa, Can you add some info? what is the asus operation mode (`Administration` / `Operation mode`)? can you ping from the mikrotik to the 192.168.209.2? Can you show the Mikrotik NAT table? Is the ASUS set to NAT the traffic to the Mikrotik? Thanks

Comment: Also both routers have a huge variety of models, if you can add the model for the asus and the routerboard

Comment: Hi, thanks. 
First I tried to set it as AP so my wireless devices will also belong to the 192.168.209.0/24 but did not know how to properly configure it in the Mirkotik. So I changed it for router mode, setting up this 10.0.0.0/24 network. 

No, I cannot ping the ASUS from the Mikrotik, I dont understand why. It is directly connected, eth2 Mikrotik 192.168.209.1 to WAN ASUS port 192.168.209.2, I send the ping from the MKT through eth2 and it timeout. 
But in the addresses table it says the network is reachable.

I cannot access the NAT table now, I will post that asap

Comment: You are right, sorry. 
Mikrotik rb3011
ASUS RTAC51u (pretty simple model)

Comment: Please, can you check on the ASUS firewall configuration, it has a `Respond ping request from WAN`, enable it so that you can better debug the connection between the rb3911 and the asus

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem setting the ASUS as Wireless Bridge mode.
From the ASUS:

Wireless setting / Bridge Tab / WDS only / Connect to AP in list: yes

Thank you all for the help provided.